# How to align text next to my Image in PHP

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am wanting the text I have above the photo on my website to be positioned on the right hand side next to the image. I have attempted to do this but the formatting must be wrong. Can anyone steer me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: you need to style it with css or change the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the element order as below, and add `float:left;` css to `.detail-broker` (Ideally not inline as I have done below). I believe that the php code still works but just double check that it is valid.

```
<?php
if($configClass['show_agent_details'] == 1){ ?>
  <h4>Contact Your Consultant</h4>
  <div class="detail-broker" style="float:left;">
  <?php echo $row->agentphoto;?>
    <div class="broker-name">
      <b><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_osproperty&task=agent_info&id=".$row->agent_id);?>"><?php echo $row->agent_name;?></a></b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php
  //echo("<div align='right'>");
  echo("Phone: <a href='tel:1300791719'>1300 791 719</a><br />");
  echo("Email: <a href='mailto:info@newrealestate.properties'>info@newrealestate.properties</a><br />");
  echo("Address: Level 4, 150 Albert Rd, South Melbourne, 3205, Melbourne, Victoria");
  //echo("</div>");
  ?>


<?php } ?>
```

[image]